# Symfony2 Service reference from mustache

Tags: php, symfony, mustache

i have a `mustache` template that has the following line

`{{{widgets.service_name.js.footer}}}`

i found the corresponding service defined in a symfony2 bundle

```
service_name:
        class: A\B\C\D\EventListener\AssetsListener
        arguments:
            - @templating
            - %a.b.timestamp%
            - %kernel.environment%
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: injectAsset, priority: -255}
```

Is there a `mustache` specific meaning in `.js.footer` (prefix to the symfony2 service name) i am unable to find any reference related to this.

Anyone could provide some pointers i would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dots in mustache tags are equivalent to either array access, properties or method calls. So this:

```
{{{widgets.service_name.js.footer}}}
```

Means something like this:

```
$widgets['service_name']['js']['footer'];
$widgets['service_name']->js->footer;
$widgets['service_name']->js()->footer();
```

… or some combination of the above. Which it actually translates to depends on what the service is, what public methods or properties it exposes, and what they return.

Here's more on [Mustache dot notation](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Dot-Notation), and on [variable resolution in Mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Variable-Resolution).